# ssh does not accept renamed key pair via config

Tags: ssh

I renamed my ssh keypair (id_rsa/id_rsa.pub → id_servername/id_servername.pub) and changed my config file accordingly

```
Host servername
    User jan
    Hostname servername.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_servername
```

Connecting with `ssh -i id_servername servername` succeeds, but ssh keeps trying id_rsa when I do not specify the keyfile explicitly (i.e. when I rely on the configuration quoted above). Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: The "Host" line in .ssh/config did not actually match the hostname I used when connecting, so the ssh client did not apply the configuration.